# div's size depending on the text inside it

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make some kind of a comment system for a forum. There are two divs, one is the comment author, the other comment content. I want the whole comment div to change height depending on the amount of text in the comment content div, but if I try to set the comment's height to auto, it just doesn't work that way, the bottom border disappears and the comment author div doesn't get a new height.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.discussion{
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}
/* LINE */
.line{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF9933;
  margin: auto;
}
/* COMMENT */
.comment{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: solid 2px ;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  border-color: #606060;
}
.comment_author{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFE5CC;
  float: left;
}
.comment_author_name{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px;
  border-color: #606060;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
}
.comment_author_picture{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-image: url(images/super.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #E0E0E0;  
}
.comment_author_rank{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.comment_content{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFCC99;
  float: right; 
}
.comment_date{
  width: 100%
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
  border-color: #606060;
}
.comment_date span{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2%;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #606060;
}
.comment_message{
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>A discussion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="discussion">
        <div class="line">
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="comment_author">
            <div class="comment_author_name">
              Jurgis
            </div>
            <div class="comment_author_picture">
            </div>
            <div class="comment_author_rank">
              Pro
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment_content">
            <div class="comment_date">
              <span>2017-08-13 23:45:23</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comment_message">
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios.
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas.
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas.
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas.
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `height`setting from `.comment` (making it `height: auto` that way) and add `background-color: #FFE5CC; overflow: auto;` to it to cover the whole left column of the box with the background color:

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.discussion{
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}
/* LINE */
.line{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF9933;
  margin: auto;
  }
/* COMMENT */
.comment{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: solid 2px ;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  border-color: #606060;
  background-color: #FFE5CC;
  overflow: auto;
}
.comment_author{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFE5CC;
  float: left;
}
.comment_author_name{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px;
  border-color: #606060;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
}
.comment_author_picture{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-image: url(images/super.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #E0E0E0;  
}
.comment_author_rank{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.comment_content{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFCC99;
  float: right; 
}
.comment_date{
  width: 100%
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
  border-color: #606060;
}
.comment_date span{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2%;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #606060;
}
.comment_message{
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>A discussion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="discussion">
        <div class="line">
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="comment_author">
            <div class="comment_author_name">
              Jurgis
            </div>
            <div class="comment_author_picture">
            </div>
            <div class="comment_author_rank">
              Pro
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment_content">
            <div class="comment_date">
              <span>2017-08-13 23:45:23</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comment_message">
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios.
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas.
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas.
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas.
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the height, below it said height 300px, just remove it.

```
.comment{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: solid 2px ;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  border-color: #606060;
}
```

You then need code to set the comment_author and comment_content to equal hights

Add this to a javascript and include it in your html file

```
var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.commonClassName').each(function(){

       $el = $(this);
       topPostion = $el.position().top;

       if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {

         // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
         for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
           rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
         }

         // set the variables for the new row
         rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
         currentRowStart = topPostion;
         currentTallest = $el.height();
         rowDivs.push($el);

       } else {

         // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
         rowDivs.push($el);
         currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);

      }

      // do the last row
       for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
         rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
       }        

    });

});
```

Then replace these

```
<div class="comment_content commonClassName">
<div class="comment_author commonClassName">
```

You need JQuery for this to work by the way...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. By setting the background color of the left-side on the .comment it will look like the left-side has the same height as the right-side.

The right-side now has a `display: inline-block`.

---

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.discussion{
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
}
/* LINE */
.line{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF9933;
  margin: auto;
}
/* COMMENT */
.comment{
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 300px; not needed */
  margin: auto;
  border-top: solid 2px ;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  border-color: #606060;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFE5CC;
}
.comment_author{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.comment_author_name{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px;
  border-color: #606060;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
}
.comment_author_picture{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-image: url(images/super.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #E0E0E0;  
}
.comment_author_rank{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.comment_content{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFCC99;
  float: right; 
}
.comment_date{
  width: 100%
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
  border-color: #606060;
}
.comment_date span{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2%;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px #606060;
}
.comment_message{
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>A discussion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="discussion">
        <div class="line">
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="comment_author">
            <div class="comment_author_name">
              Jurgis
            </div>
            <div class="comment_author_picture">
            </div>
            <div class="comment_author_rank">
              Pro
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment_content">
            <div class="comment_date">
              <span>2017-08-13 23:45:23</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comment_message">
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios.
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas.
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas.
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas.
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas. 
              Lorem ipsum (trump. lipsum) yra tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino industrijoje jau nuo XVI amžiaus pradžios. 
              Jis naudojamas parodyti grafinio pristatymo elementus, tokius kaip tipografija, dizainas ar šriftas. 
              Jis taip pat kūrimo stadijoje naudojamas kaip kai kurių produktų aprašymų tekstas, prieš tai kai įrašomas tikrasis tekstas.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```